# Automatically deleting a given word (or value) upon inserting a text into MySql table

Tags: php, mysql, string-interpolation

I know similar questions have been asked before, but this is slightly different.

I just activated an on-line sms gateway service, which lets you **receive messages** online.

A common numeration, a shared common number is assigned for any incoming message, which are then sorted and assigned to the specific customer through **a chosen identification keyword** displayed at the ***beginning of the text***.

The identification keyword is an aplhanumeric value.

[see an example here](http://www.skebby.com/sms-gateway/sms-api/receiving-text-messaging/)

Forwarding the incoming texts to a DB table through a *php* [POST] page is what I am doing; and, as you may imagine, getting rid of the initial keyword upon entry insertion is my wish (it's not done by default).

All incoming mesagges stored in the table start with the same word, which is of course unnecessary and reduntant in terms of data conservation

How can I do this? A clear advantage here is that the key is unique and unchanged.

Here is the script I currently use in my php page, where texts are forwarded.
(those POST arguments are the ones provided by the service administrator)

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='POST') 
{
echo 'No Script Here!';
exit;
}

$con = new mysqli('localhost','','','');


$insert_sms_success = FALSE;

if (mysqli_connect_errno()==0)
{ 
$sent_dt = $_POST['Timestamp'];
$txt = $_POST['Body']; 
$sender_number = $_POST['Sender'];   
$shared_number = $_POST['Destination'];

$txt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $txt);
$sender_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $sender_number);

$sql="INSERT INTO SMS_IN_A(sms_text,sender_number,sent_dt) VALUES ('$txt','$sender_number','$sent_dt')";

$insert_sms_success = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

mysqli_close($con);
}

if ($insert_sms_success)
{
}
else 
{  
http_response_code(500);
}                                          
?>
```

ps: as you can see all the incoming texts begin with the same word, which in the case I have chosen is "posto"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA5tC.jpg)

Comment: You need to remove said part from the text using php, not MySQL(i).

Comment: I am sorry, where did I say that I want to use MySql(i)?

Comment: For me at lease, the title implied that ("Automatically ... upon inserting ... into MySql). Basically you're asking how to perform basic string manipulation using PHP; I can assure you this topic was covered very widely in Stack Overflow :).

Comment: ok, I borrowed the expressione hat you mentioned "basic string manipulation" and found some result with google.
I understand that you mainly use REPLACE.
That could be ok for me (if I knew how to use it), but I would also love if I could just remove the key right from the database at the moment of insertion ..

Answer (score 0):

First, I HIGHLY recommend switching to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) and use [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to sanitize your data before inserting it into the database. Right now you are vulnerable to a SQL Injection since you are inserting body text from a text message.

That being said, you would want to just use PHPs string manipulation methods to remove the first word.

```
$s = 'posto my text message';
$s = substr($s, strpos($s, ' ')); // $s = 'my text message'
```

Now, if you absolutely **MUST** do it with SQL, you can do it like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO SMS_IN_A(sms_text,sender_number,sent_dt) VALUES (
            SUBSTRING('$txt', LOCATE(' ', '$txt')),
            '$sender_number',
            '$sent_dt')"
```

Again, really *really* don't recommend this as it would be very easy for someone to send malicious SQL in the text body that could really ruin your day (and your database)

Comment: ok thanks
security is an issue for me too and that was basically an idea too

Now I am preparing a longer answer, in the meantime thanks

Comment: Frank sorry to bother, just a warn to let you know you have a new answer and that I look forward to hearing from you